# sudo tasksel install lamp-server

Tags: lamp

установка начинается и слетает почему, что исправить? чтоб [image: установка]lamp-server проинсталило до конца.

Comment: Што-а? Ставьте пакетами через пакетный менеджер (apt-get, yum, zypper и т.п.)

Comment: Выше ответили верно, через apt-get ставьте. Можете проверить репозитории, иногда туда нужно дописать\обновить ссылку. Попытайтесь собрать из исходников.